# how to create "role" with "Another AWS account" role type by cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, user-roles

I am trying to write a batch file in windows to do below steps by CLI command([actual example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)), but I don't know how to create a role and set cli command for "Another AWS account" role type. Do you mind help me?

> In the navigation pane on the left, choose Roles and then choose
>   **Create role**.
>
> Choose the **Another AWS account** role type.
>
> For Account ID, type the **Development account ID**.
>
> This tutorial uses the example account ID 111111111111 for the
>   Development account. You should use a valid account ID. If you use an
>   invalid account ID, such as 111111111111, IAM does not let you create
>   the new role.
>
> For now you do not need to require an external ID, or require users to
>   have multi-factor authentication (MFA) in order to assume the role. So
>   leave these options unselected. For more information, see Using
>   Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) in AWS
>
> Choose Next: Permissions to set the permissions that will be
>   associated with the role.

my codes for creating a role:

```
call aws iam create-role --role-name xxx-S3-Role --assume-role-policy-document file://trustpolicy.json
```

my trustpolicy.json

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::222222075333:role/xxx-S3-Role"
  }]
}
```

I am receiving below error:

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: Has prohibited field Resource
```

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem here? Any error messages or what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Marcin: I added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by changing two parts.

1- by fix the path of policy

```
aws iam create-role --role-name xxx-S3-Role --assume-role-policy-document file://c:\foldername\trustpolicy.json
```

2- I change the format of the policy by reverse engineering a policy that I created from the console, the format is in below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222075333:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```